# Swift, struct. How to simplify struct multiple property .dot accessors?

Tags: swift, struct

I have some structs that represent locations on the Earth that represent a simple ***lat/lon*** location (`Point2D`), ***lat/lon/height*** location (`Point3D`), and a named location such as an airport ***name/lat/lon/height*** location (`Airport`).

```swift
struct Point2D {
  var lat: Double
  var lon: Double
}

struct Point3D {
  var point2D: Point2D
  var height_m: Double
}

struct Airport {
  var name: String
  var point3D: Point3D
}
```

These structs are used hierarchically which works fine, but it does cause some long .dot access when getting data out of an airport instance.  For example, to get the airport's latitude value is `airport.point3D.point2D.lat` which is not ideal.

```swift
let airportLHR1 = Airport(name: "LHR", point3D: Point3D(point2D: Point2D(lat: 51.5, lon: -0.5), height_m: 25.0))
print("Airport: \(airportLHR1.name). Lat,Lon: \(airportLHR1.point3D.point2D.lat), \(airportLHR1.point3D.point2D.lon)")
// --> Airport: LHR. Lat,Lon: 51.5, -0.5
```

I have refactored the airport struct to 'flatten' the property .dot access, but I feel that there may be a better way to achieve this.

```swift
struct Airport2 {
  var name: String
  private var _point3D: Point3D
  var lat:      Double  { get { _point3D.point2D.lat } set { _point3D.point2D.lat = newValue } }
  var lon:      Double  { get { _point3D.point2D.lon } set { _point3D.point2D.lon = newValue } }
  var height_m: Double  { get { _point3D.height_m }    set { _point3D.height_m = newValue } }

  init(name: String, lat: Double, lon: Double, height_m: Double) {
    self.name = name
    self._point3D = Point3D(point2D: Point2D(lat: lat, lon: lon), height_m: height_m)
  }
}
```

Accessing the airport's data is now much simpler...

```swift
let airportLHR2 = Airport2(name: "LHR", lat: 51.5, lon: -0.5, height_m: 25.0)
print("Airport: \(airportLHR2.name). Lat,Lon: \(airportLHR2.lat), \(airportLHR2.lon)")
// --> Airport: LHR. Lat,Lon: 51.5, -0.5
```

... but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Personally, I might just keep the original structure and then have extension with convenience getters, e.g. `extension Airport { var lat: Double { point3D.point2D.lat } }`. You presumably don't need the setter. And this removes the `get`/`set` noise.

Comment: A complete aside, but CoreLocation already has naming conventions for 3D and 2D geolocation points, e.g. a “coordinate” is a lat/long and a “location” is an altitude/coordinate (and a “placemark” is a name/location). You might want to contemplate whether this naming convention is preferable to point2D/point3D...

Comment: What is the airport's height? Is it altitude?

Comment: @Rob I like the extension alternative, although in some circumstances I do still need setters.  I have looked at CoreLocation and I agree that keeping with the 'standard' naming convention is probably good.  

I don't use CoreLocation as it does allow for a location to be created that has invalid lat,lon values.
e.g.  `let location = CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(111.1), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(222.2))`  something I don't want in the app I writing.

Comment: @liquid This is just a simplified example, so the height value is somewhat arbitrary in this example.  In my actual code, I also have created a reference datum object (e.g. WGS84), so the height is then the height above the WGS84 ellipsoid, which is effectively the height above mean sea level (kind of!  :) )

Comment: @liquid I will certainly look at using an extension of CLLocation if/when I run my code on an iPhone/iPad device.  Not mentioned in my original question, my app currently does **LOTS** of number crunching which requires the lat/lon values to be in radians, so I wanted to keep things simple without the additional stuff that comes with CoreLocation.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting using core location. I was suggesting mirroring/adopting their naming convention. Why introduce a completely different set of names when there is an existing, well-established, convention?

Comment: @Rob. I understood what you meant.  Changing my struct names to be CL-like would be a good change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
struct Coordinate {
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
}

struct Location {
    let coordinate: Coordinate
    let altitude: Double
}

struct Airport {
    let name: String
    let location: Location
}

extension Airport {
    var latitude: Double { location.coordinate.latitude }
    var longitude: Double { location.coordinate.longitude }
}
```

Above, following best practices, I have favored immutability. But if you really need mutability:

```swift
struct Coordinate {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
}

struct Location {
    var coordinate: Coordinate
    var altitude: Double
}

struct Airport {
    var name: String
    var location: Location
}

extension Airport {
    var latitude: Double {
        get { location.coordinate.latitude }
        set { location.coordinate.latitude = newValue }
    }

    var longitude: Double {
        get { location.coordinate.longitude }
        set { location.coordinate.longitude = newValue }
    }
}
```

---

Unrelated, but I would probably move these computed properties into a `Place` protocol:

```swift
protocol Place {
    var name: String { get }
    var location: Location { get }
}

extension Place {
    var latitude: Double { location.coordinate.latitude }
    var longitude: Double { location.coordinate.longitude }
}

struct Airport: Place {
    let name: String
    let location: Location
}
```

That way you can define places that are not airports, too, and not have to repeat these computed properties.

Comment: Nice.  I do indeed need to allow for other types of places (airports, waypoints, navaids, runways, runway thresholds etc) - So I shall be sure to take your suggestions on board.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean altitude by `height`, you can simply make use of `CLLocation`, and optionally extend it with a convenience initializer to make life a little easier.

```
extension CLLocation {
    convenience init(lat: CLLocationDegrees, lon: CLLocationDegrees, alt: CLLocationDistance) {
        self.init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon),
                  altitude: alt,
                  horizontalAccuracy: 0,
                  verticalAccuracy: 0,
                  timestamp: .now)
    }
}

struct Airport {
    let name: String
    let loc: CLLocation
}

let lax = Airport(name: "LAX", loc: CLLocation(lat: 33.9416, lon: -118.4085, alt: 39.0144))

print(lax.loc.coordinate.longitude) // -118.4085
print(lax.loc.altitude) // 39.0144
```

Comment: OP has no idea where that `.now` is coming from. Why not simply `Date()`?. Btw be careful with what your custom property `.now` is returning. If it is not simply the `Date()` value its implementation is wrong.

Comment: @LeoDabus `Date()` and `.now` will give you the exact same point in time.

Comment: Again if your `now` property doesn't return `Date()` it is wrong. Feel free to add its declaration to your post.

Comment: @LeoDabus `.now` does return a `Date`.

Comment: I am pretty sure it does. My concern is which date. If you don't show its declaration you will never now if it is ok or not.

Comment: @LeoDabus that's for OP to figure out if they even want to account for time. As of right now, LAX is at those coordinates at that altitude. The `timestamp` property of `CLLocation` is meant to be used for moving objects. Airports don't move very much aside from tectonic shift. If the OP wants to account for time in the context of a flight schedule, for example, I can't imagine they would couple it with coordinate and altitude of the airport itself.

Comment: My main point here is to warn about your now implementation. Not related to the OP post in any way. Again if you need to create a date that represents now use `Date()` don't use whatever you have declared under that `now` property.

Comment: As the OP, I have no interest in time for my specific solution.  I specifically didn’t use CL in my code.  However, there may be others with similar problem where CL does work for them.

Comment: @LeoDabus I just don't share your paranoia over the syntax choice, which is all it is. They are identical. Do you not use `.zero` in place of `CGPoint()` when you need a zeroed-out point?

Comment: @Rob good catch, I had originally set it for `kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters` because it felt appropriate with the coordinates I hastily pulled from Google but defaulted to the default when I posted. I don't even know if `0` is technically appropriate given the coordinates I used but definitely better than negative, you are right.

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm not sure if I understand your objection to `Date.now`. It is a Foundation property introduced in iOS 15. Sure, if you need to support prior OS versions, use `Date()`, but `Date.now` is valid.

Comment: @Rob I was concerned because I have seen wrong implementations of it. Glad they have added it. It will avoid such issues.

Comment: “I don't even know if 0 is technically appropriate [for `horizontalAccuracy` and `verticalAccuracy`] ...” - It is a valid value. If you use the built in `CLLocation(latitude:longitude:)` the `horizontalAccuracy` is `0`. We just avoid negative values (unless, of course, you don't have a `altitude`, for example). But `0` is the default that the API uses...